# How to return the result from an aggregate() call

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I can't figure out how to return the data from an aggregation function to be handled in my code

```
cursor = db.data.aggregate
([
    {'$unwind': '$list'},
    {'$sort': {'_id': 1, 'list.itemcode':1}},
    {'$group':{'_id': '$key', 'list': {'$push': '$itemcode'}}}
], cursor={})

print cursor
```

I'm on Mongo 2.65 and pymongo 2.72. Although the docs say I should be able to pass the cursor arg, this gives me a syntax error. Without it, cursor returns <bound method Collection.aggregate of Collection..>

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a { in the wrong spot. Try

```
cursor = db.data.aggregate
([
    {'$unwind': '$list'},
    {'$sort': {'_id': 1, 'list.itemcode':1}},
    {'$group':{ '_id': '$key' }, 'list': {'$push': '$itemcode'}}
], cursor={})
```

and if that doesn't work, please edit the question to include the errors that you're getting.